# Output of groups command for secondary groups differ from the out of id command

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, users

As I know the `groups` command and the `id` command should both in their output display the secondary groups of a user.
But in my case the output differ from each other:

```
$ id <username>
uid=1000(username) gid=1000(username) groups=1000(username)

$ groups
username adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare libvirt
```

Im am using Ubuntu version 18.04.1.

I also check the `/etc/group` file and I don't see any entry for the groups that the `groups` command shows related to the specified username. Should it not actually be the secondary group information to username mapping in this file? I was expecting that next to the name of the group, lets say `cdrom`, to see the username I used for the groups command!

If it helps, the output of the `ps -o egid,rgid,pid,ppid,cmd | grep bash` command is:

```
1000   1000   30061   29959   /bin/bash
1000   1000   31747   30061   grep --color=auto bash
```

Update:
I checked that the output of the `id` command without specifying a username displays all the groups like the `groups` command but executing the same command specifying the username `id username` does not shows the other groups.
In the man page of the `id` command it says.

id [OPTION]...[USER]
Print user and group information for the specified USER, or (when USER omitted) for the current user.

In this case it should be the same output because it is about the same user.

Comment: what is the output for `ps -o egid,rgid,pid,ppid,cmd | grep bash`. put your shell if you are not using `bash`. (`zsh`, `csh`,...)

Comment: @binarysta I added the output of that command to my question. Please see it there. Thnx.

Comment: so what if you start a new shell and check again the `id` and `groups`? the result is same?

Comment: @binarysta yes it is the same. Please check also my last update. `id` and `groups` displays the same output but the `id <username>` does not display the other groups.

Comment: ok is there any other user with 1000 uid? `grep 1000 /etc/passwd` ?

Comment: @binarysta no there is none else with this uid. There is only one entry `username:x:1000:1000:username,,,:/home/username:/bin/bash`. I don't know if it helps, but when I try `newgrp cdrom` and then enter the password, it shows me this error `newgrp: failed to crypt password with previous salt: Invalid argument`.

Comment: The erroneous assumption underpinning the first sentence is such a fundamental part of `id` that it comes up in numerous answer and question comments, but not (until now) as the actual main question and answer.  I was surprised to be unable to find a duplicate Q&A.

Comment: And what is the result for `grep 1000 /etc/group` ?

Comment: @binarysta The output is `username:x:1000:username`